# Is Kubernetes another Docker but in largescale?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am new to Docker. From what I understood both Docker and Kubernetes manage multiple containers.

Kubernetes is more a large-scale container management with an abstraction layer compared to Docker. Isn't it possible to duplicate this scenario of abstraction in Docker? If so, then why do we say that it is purely different from each other? How exactly does Kubernetes differ from Docker with its application?

I went through some explanations but still being confused regarding this question.Could anyone help me with a good explanation or provide some materials that would help me clear this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation given. It helped me to get some idea. But what I was more curious on is that as both Kubernetes and Docker are capable of running images in containers as their main task, the motivation for kubernetes was to allow to expand the container management? I am wrong in any way?

Comment: Yes right you are it’s more of management tools and give flexibility, if you want to run 3 replica of one image in docker how you will do it and load balance traffic to all ? What Kubernetes uses internally as container runtime did you checked that ?

Comment: We can run multiple containers of the same image in Docker, isn't it? wouldn't that be considered as running replicas? And for the load balancing I guess there isn't a way in docker but can be done in Kubernetes using pods and services. It seems to be an interesting topic to look into. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Docker** is a **container runtime tool** first; Kubernetes cannot be compared to Docker. The PODs are scheduled or managed by the orchestration platform known as Kubernetes.

You may compare **Kubernetes** with **Docker swarm** in several ways.

Kubernetes have some better options like

- Distribution of containers based on the requirement (Run ML container on Graphics card Nodes, CPU required container on CPU intensive VMs or Node pool)
- Scaling based on Metrics - **HPA & VPA**
- Observability across platform - **Easy to add/integrate other solutions**
- RBAC & Security options - **Firewall rules, Network policies**
- Loadbalancing internally with **Service**
- Traffic routing option & pluggable solutions - **Istio, LinkerD**
- Managed services by cloud providers - **EKS, GKE, OKE**
- Variety of Volume options - **PV, PVC backed by SSD, NFS, CSI driver options**